# Is there an event for when a control has finished drawing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a calendar control that I'm creating in code and there's a noticable pause between its creation and when it appear on the screen.

How can I show a spinner during this delay?

Comment: Is the creation just slow or are you getting data from an external source. Otherwise you could add a delegate to the call (or callback) so when fetching the data is done you could hide the spinner. As far as I know there isn't a event/delegate when the drawing is finished

Comment: Creation is slow. Data is fetched so perhaps I'll go on that, as you suggest. It's unlikely that the data would return before the control has finished drawing.

Comment: Do you have published your control's source code? I thought there were same events to deal with this on the platform's side like `OnFinishInflate` or `OnLayout` (Android).

Comment: It's Telerik for Xamarin.Forms Calendar control.